# Serde Deserializer, how to have distinct behavior while decoding an `u8` directly and a `u8` in a `Vec<u8>`

Tags: rust, serde

I'm writing a `Deserializer` for a format that already exists, but the format has one peculiarity which I don't know how to implement in serde:

```
// pseudo code
fn example(){
   // when decoding an u8 directly, the value 0x00 is invalid
   assert!(<u8>::deserialize(Format::from_bytes(&[0x00u8])).is_err());

   // however, when decoding an u8 through a Vec<u8> 0x00 is valid
   //
   // The problem is that this will first call `deserialize_seq`, which
   // will then use the same function as `<u8>::deserialize`, but I need
   // it to call a different method which actually accepts the value 0x00
   assert_eq!(<Vec<u8>>::deserialize(Format::from_bytes(&[0x00u8])), vec![0x00]);
}
```

The problem is that the original implementation is not generic, and it has an implementation for `u8` [which rejects the value `0x00`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/8e121591acd63e7def9146fbf6bee0693fee3450/rlp/src/impls.rs#L114), and a `Vec<u8>` [which accepts it](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/8e121591acd63e7def9146fbf6bee0693fee3450/rlp/src/impls.rs#L66).

It looks like I need some kind of runtime type information to replicate this within a serde deserializer, any way of implementing this?

Comment: I think [`"serde_bytes"`](https://github.com/serde-rs/bytes) would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kmdreko for the pointer, that was very helpful.

So the problem I had was that the [default behavior](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/ef6ed1d1be9a181a3a6d19d0860befe5d7b279b7/serde/src/de/impls.rs#L880) of `serde::de::Deserialize` for `Vec<T>` created a visitor [parametrized on `T`](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/ef6ed1d1be9a181a3a6d19d0860befe5d7b279b7/serde/src/de/impls.rs#L857), forcing the *items of* a `Vec<u8>` to use the same deserialization function as `u8`. Because serde provides a default implementation for `Vec<T>`, and rust doesn't support overloading, and [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) hasn't landed, I couldn't simply do `impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Vec<u8>`. The work around was to introduce a unit struct, which I named `DirectBytes`, and code a `impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for DirectBytes` which uses `deserialize_byte_buf` instead of `deserialize_seq`.

`serde_bytes` is a bit more complicated, it not only has these "proxy" structs, but it also has its own trait named `Deserialize`, which I suppose is necessary for the macro `#[serde(with="..")]` to work properly. I also don't know how to implement this behavior if `deserialize_byte_buf` didn't happen to do what I needed, but for my problem at hand the wrapping type seems good enough.